# Podio::authenticate_with_app($app_id, $app_token); is not working

Tags: api, podio

My client has a site on 'ideacontainer.net/real_coffee/'. Now I guess he has accidentally deleted the app then recovered it. But from that time he is not able to access his site.

This is the code in his index file

```
require_once 'podio-php-master/PodioAPI.php';
$client_id = "some-client-id";
$client_secret = "3zLcr...";
$app_id = "17373109";
$app_token = "48148cfca3c...";
Podio::setup($client_id, $client_secret);
Podio::authenticate_with_app($app_id, $app_token);
```

When I am commenting it line by line it is working till "Podio::authenticate_with_app($app_id, $app_token);" line. So I think the problem is in this line.

Please let me know the solution.

Thanks

Shashank Kumar

Comment: is there any error returned? can you verify that app_id and app_token has correct values?

Comment: your client_id is disabled and you will have to create new one, also you will have to re-generate app token and re-check app_id

Comment: Its shows error 500. The URL is http://ideacontainer.net/real_coffee/. 
Application - real coffee
 Client ID - real-coffee-uin3cq
 Client Secret - HxKOtYXcjA2Ns0lkIwtxuquiLhWuE7OoHH0HR3Yx8ZL44TWJBTDMXffwNBK4yjTr
App ID for PRO Database: - 17434150
 Token for PRO Database: - bd36945943474efe96e14b99e72a08e3

I have just regenerated all the values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create new client (the one mentioned in your code as `client_id`), also you will have to re-generate app token and re-check app_id. If it still doesn't work, please provide full error message returned from Podio API.

Comment: Its shows error 500. The URL is http://ideacontainer.net/real_coffee/. 
Application - real coffee
 Client ID - real-coffee-uin3cq
 Client Secret - HxKOtYXcjA2Ns0lkIwtxuquiLhWuE7OoHH0HR3Yx8ZL44TWJBTDMXffwNBK4yjTr
App ID for PRO Database: - 17434150
 Token for PRO Database: - bd36945943474efe96e14b99e72a08e3

I have just regenerated all the values.

Comment: Please stop sharing your access credentials. I've invalidated them (again).

Comment: What I was asking for: full error message from Podio API

Comment: When I uncomment that authenticate line Its shows error 500 only

Comment: Sorry, but it's not clear where 500 error is coming from. I can help troubleshooting if it's from Podio API, but need full stacktrace and full error message.